# Uncloseable virus-like window asking to connect to a server. How to kill it?

Tags: macos, bug

I have the following window from unknown application appearing

[image]

if I press `Cancel` it appears again. If I enter any password it thrills meaning password is wrong. If I reboot it appears again. Killing all applications and restarting Finder doesn't help.

Is it possible to stop this window from appearing? The only way I found is to move it out of screen, but small margin is still visible.

---

I can't connect to this server with Finder and browse it's files. This fact doesn't affect the problem in any way: window still appears and still uncloseable.

Comment: It is not an *"unknown application."* It is asking for credentials to connect to another Mac or PC (a server or really any network device) on the network named "sagittarius-a"

Comment: Yes I understand, but I don't want to connect with it. Can I stop these attempts?

Comment: Not sure the new title helps. Does the server name ring a bell? Does it happen only in one user account or in all? What is in your Login Items? There are several things which can trigger this, we need your help to find it.

Comment: I don't understand what "server name ringing a bell" means. It is a real server in my network. It is linux server with samba. I have only one user account on my Macbook. I don't know what are "login items".

Comment: Probably cleaning login items helped. But don't know what it was. There was nothing criminal there

Comment: „Something“ on your Mac tries to access the file server or a file stored there when you login, the question is what. Check the apps which get started automatically in System Preferences->Users and remove them all. The quit all running applications and reboot. Does the problem occur again?

Comment: @Dims The expression "does _x_ ring a bell?" means "do you recognise _x_?". In other words, do you recognise the server named `sagittarius-a`? Maybe someone who you know may recognise it? Just trying to be helpful here.